# Mac Terminal Slow after upgrading to PHP7.3

Tags: terminal, bash, php

I had my  Mid 2013 macbook air running Mojave (10.14.5) with PHP 7.1.23 updated to PHP  7.3 from https://php-osx.liip.ch/ using the command 
`curl -s https://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 7.3` .

Everything went fine and i added `export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH` to my bash_profile to adjust PATH to include the installed directory . Once i sourced the bash_profile the terminal just went really slow . An `ls` command is taking almost 3s in $HOME .

I tried deleting the added export and the terminal is working really fine ( ls is almost instantaneous )  but the PHP version is the old one . Do anybody have any idea on what is going on ?

I tried it both on zsh and bash and both are showing the same behaviour .

Comment: What's in the /usr/local/php5/bin folder? (could you attach output from ls)... I'm wondering if perhaps it contains other commands than just php itself.

Comment: @jksoegaard it has total 100520   which includes postmaster for postgres , active-entropy-php.py and several other php packages.

Comment: The folder contains 100520 files? Seems quite excessive? - Copy the php binary to a different folder and add that to your path instead.

Comment: Let me check   ...... i just did as the website said  ......